# Is Oracle Cloud Infrastructure support tagging at object level?

Tags: python, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-object-storage

I was going through the oci python SDK for OCI. I am unable to find any way to add tags to object storage objects from the SDK. that's why got a doubt whether OCI supports tagging at the object level for object storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCI object storage doesn't support tagging at the `object` level. It supports tagging only at the `bucket` level. Please see the below table for all the supported resources for tagging.

[https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Tagging/Concepts/taggingoverview.htm#:~:text=256%20characters-,Resources%20That%20Can%20Be%20Tagged,-The%20following%20table](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Tagging/Concepts/taggingoverview.htm#:%7E:text=256%20characters-,Resources%20That%20Can%20Be%20Tagged,-The%20following%20table)

Thanks